# resultados diferentes con la misma consulta en T-SQL y LinQ en un proyecto de EF Core y Angular

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando recuperar registros de una base de datos en Azure y para las comprobaciones ejecuto queries en T-SQL directamente y luego las paso a LINQ contra el contexto de EF Core, pero me estoy encontrando con este problema

[image: t-sql]

```
select FechaOrientativa,id, Archivo, Estado, Estudiar, Descripcion
from Concursos
where FechaOrientativa>=CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) and Estudiar='pt'
order by FechaOrientativa, Archivo, Estado
```

Cuando filtro por los registros con FechaOrientativa mayor o igual a Hoy el campo Estudira igual a 'pt' obtengo 2.296 registro

Ahora en Angular hago http.Get a mi Web API donde ejecuto lo siguiente

```
[HttpGet("sintratar")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Concurso>>> GetConcursosSinTratar()
{
  return await _context.Concursos.Where(c => c.Estudiar == "pt" && c.FechaOrientativa >= DateTime.Now).OrderBy(c => c.FechaOrientativa).ToListAsync();
}
```

Y ante mi sorpresa recibo solo 2.151 registros y no logro encontrar una explicación

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el DateTime.Now que incluye la hora.

Para obtener el mismo resutado que la querrá de T-SQL se usa DateTime.Today

```
return await _context.Concursos
.Where(c => c.Estudiar == "pt" && c.FechaOrientativa >= DateTime.Today)
.OrderBy(c => c.FechaOrientativa)
.ToListAsync();
```